# Custom Component not appearing

Tags: react-native

I made a custom bottom Navbar for my React-Native App which I want to stick at the bottom of the screen.

This is what it looks like

```
   <View style={styles.NavBarBottom}>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.activeTab("home")}>
                        <Text> <Icon name="bitcoin" size={30} color={ this.state.activeTab == "home" ? "#fbc02d" : "white"} /></Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>



                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.activeTab("News")}>
                        <Text> <Icons name="news" size={30} color={this.state.activeTab == "News" ? "#fbc02d" : "white"} /> </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

</View>
```

where Styles are this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    NavBarBottom : {
      paddingTop: 8,
      borderTopWidth: 2,
      backgroundColor: "#005cb2",
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "space-around",
      padding: 5,
    }
  })
```

Now this successfully works and show in case of Home Screen but on another screen when I import it, It appears only when the content is loading and afterwards it doesn't appear (attaching the GIF for the same in end). Also on the page where I am just passing the props, it doesn't appear

The code for other page would be

```
<View> 
   <Header 
    navigation = {this.props.navigation} 
    enable = "true" />   
     <ScrollView>
    <View style={listOfCurrencies}>

       { CurrencyDisplay.map(data => 
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={IndvidualCurrencyMain}> 
         <Text  style={dataLong}> {data["long"]}</Text>
             <Text  style={dataShort}>{data["short"]}</Text> 
     </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>)}

 </View>
</ScrollView> 
<BottomNavigation />
</View>
```

With Styles like this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
listOfCurrencies: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        marginBottom: 60
    }, 
    IndvidualCurrencyMain: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 80,
        alignItems: "center",
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginLeft: 3,
        marginRight: 3,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 5

    },
    dataLong:{
        marginLeft: 3,
        width: 150
    },
    dataShort: {
        marginLeft: "48%",
        marginRight: 5
    },
    index: {
        marginLeft: 2,
        width: 20
    }
})
```

Any idea why it won't be appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this just by adding the main view flex:1 style

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. where should I add `flex:1`? in the component where I am importing my BottomNavigation or in BottomNavigation?

Comment: In main View of your screen 
Add styles to it

Comment: That works. Will mark it answer after couple of minutes thanks :) 
Also, Can you add what does Flex: 1 do in your answer (or actually flex: number?)

Comment: flex is a positive number, it makes the component flexible and it will be sized proportionally to its flex value. So a component with flex set to 2 will take twice the space as a component with flex set to 1.

When flex is 0, the component is sized according to width and height and it is inflexible.

When flex is -1, the component is normally sized according to width and height. However, if there's not enough space, the component will shrink to its minWidth and minHeight.